# OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, weasyprint

my view

```
@api_view(['GET'])
    @renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,TemplateHTMLRenderer,BrowsableAPIRenderer))
    def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
    # def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
        order = get_object_or_404(Direct, id=order_id)
        price=order.price
        discount=order.discount
        total=price-discount
        html = render_to_string('bill/bill.html',
        {'order': order,'total':total})
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=\
        "order_{}.pdf"'.format(order.id)
        weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response,
        stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(
        settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')])
        return response
```

and when i tried to run the server or  try to run the weasyprint code
i'm fired up with an error
as

```
  raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))

OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2
```

i have updated my environment variables as well

```
C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin
```

to this location

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Cygwin development libraries for pixman (libpixman1-devel), png, pango, and poppler (PDF generation) are installed.  To do this, run the Cygwin setup program and look for pixman, poppler, and libpng, and install the *devel* libraries.

I observed, when I installed the development libraries for Pango, that it installed special "GTK" versions of Cairo and other deps.

Once I installed those Cygwin libraries, everything worked and the above error message went away (I also compiled and installed Pixman from source, which may or may not been part of the fix).